# Обособление слова "наоборот"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

**Женшина разрушает гармонию, а Ипполита, наоборот, ее создает.**

Здесь после "наоборот" не лучше ли поставить тире?

Answer (score 1):

**Женшина разрушает гармонию, а Ипполита, наоборот, ее создает.**

В этом предложении лучше **оставить запятые**: это сложносочиненное предложение, союз на месте, нет неполных конструкций. То есть нет оснований для постановки тире и увеличенной паузы.

Обособление тире ― это **авторский вариант**, но здесь он не очень подходит, так как интонация предложения строится на противопоставлении первой и второй части.

Сравнить:  **В детстве он много читал. А я ― наоборот ― рос совершенно здоровым…**  [Сергей Довлатов. Наши (1983)]

Здесь тоже авторское обособление, но сложное предложение разделено на два простых предложения.

**Комментарий**

Вообще же говоря, тире в предложениях со словом "напротив" нередко встречается в силу разных причин. Также важно отметить, что ***наоборот*** может быть **наречием** (= обозначение  противоположного порядка действия) или **вводным словом** (= в противоположность сказанному, ожидаемому).

**Пунктуация может быть разной**: например, обособление запятыми вводного слова или одно тире для наречия перед пояснительной конструкцией.

Кроме того, всегда возможен **авторский выбор** знака для  вводного слова (запятые или тире).

**Примеры с тире**

1) Пропущен союз А при однородных членах: Государство при этом не собирается бросать деньги на ветер ― **наоборот,** рассчитывает на свою долю в сборах.

2) Наречие в неполном предложении: Тепло потечёт не от горячих тел к холодным, **а наоборот ―** от холодных к горячим, а энтропия замкнутых систем станет уменьшаться.

3) Наречие и далее пояснение (ставится двоеточие или тире): **Или наоборот** ― с почерком проблем нет, а слова разбирает по слогам, как маленький. **И наоборот**: простейший электрон сам может оказаться вселенной.

4) Наречие + пояснение: Подъём же **наоборот**― по тросу с самостраховкой за верёвку.

5) Наречие + пояснение: Мы не зарабатываем на этом деньги, мы **наоборот** ― вкладываем деньги в смысловую, интересную и важную на наш взгляд историю и хотим, чтобы все его посмотрели.